# Custom Toast on Utills class

Tags: java, android, toast

I want to be able to call a Utills class method to pop custom Toast messages on screen.

My code:

```
static public void ShowToast(Context context,String message, int duration)
 {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

    // Inflate the Layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);
    // Set the Text to show in TextView
    text.setText(message);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(duration);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
 }
```

I have a proble with line 4 where i call

```
(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout)
```

I have a compilation error which states:

> The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type SystemUtills

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: ref this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView%20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findViewById` is a method of Activity, so in this line

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
```

you need `context.findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout)`

That's the reason for that compile time error.

Comment: I tried it, it gives: "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Context" any ideas whay?

Comment: findViewById is a method of Activity, not of Context. if you are calling ShowToast from an Activity and passing "this" as argument, you can cast context to activity: ((Activity)context).findViewById

Comment: Ok, adding a (ViewGroup) cast to start of param and its working.